# Get count of records of the top 3 rows and compare the counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2016, I have a query as such:

```
  SELECT [Report_date], count(distinct indv_id)
  FROM
  [dbo].[STG_TABLE] group by report_date order by report_date desc
```

I get the results as below:

```
Report_date (No column name)
2020-08-21  47918
2020-08-12  968065
2020-07-31  977804
```

Now I want to compare the difference between the counts in each row. If the difference is more than 10%, then I need to send an email out in the SSIS package.

How can I go through each row and calculate the difference? I want to look at the first row and compare it with the second row.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  Difference of *what* in each row?  There is only one number.  10% compared to *what*?

Comment: Do you want to compare the adjacent rows or you want to compare every row, if 1st case if true then below response from Gordon will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question seems to be about calculating the ratios between rows.  For that, use `lag()`.  To get the ratio:

```
SELECT [Report_date], COUNT(DISTINCT indv_id),
       (COUNT(DISTINCT indv_id) * 1.0 / LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT indv_id)) OVER (ORDER BY report_date))
FROM [dbo].[STG_TABLE] 
GROUP BY report_date 
ORDER BYreport_date DESC;
```

I'm not sure what results you want, but this is the basic information.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfect.  
I did a select top 3 and got these resutls:
Report_date (No column name) (No column name)
2020-08-31 47918 1.000000000000
2020-08-21 47918 0.049498742336
2020-08-12 968065 0.990039926201